# flash professional cs 6 include XML file in published swf

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, publish

I am making a game with flash professional and action-script 3.0, that uses XML files for the levels. The code reads it and makes the level accordingly, every thing works fine, except when i publish to an external source, the code can no longer see the XML files.
In flash pro cs6 is there any way to "attatch" the XML files to the published .swf so when it moves to another location, it can see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using external XML files you could just create XML variables inside your game code. See the first two examples here about creating an XML object from an XML: [Initializing XML variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f95.html)

Comment: Yes i know that, but my level editor makes the actual levels and then creates a xml file that represents the level. So, is it at all possible to attatch xml files to the swf when published? This is what i would realy like to do, and if its not possible, what can i do to allow the level editor add levels to my game, without having to hardcode it myself.

Comment: You can't "attach" the files. But you could upload them with the SWF, or (as Krasimir suggests) upload them to a central location and load them from there. I was suggesting that you just copy and paste the XML from your level generator into variables inside your game. It's an extra step, but it's the only way to have that data included with the SWF.

Comment: Ok, well i am going to copy and paste the xml into its own class, so i'll have a class for every level, its more work but i guess its not too bad. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you upload the xml on your own server and directly make requests there. For example your xml may be on *http://yoursite.com/gameeditor/level1.xml*. So, instead of using relative paths while loading the xml just use the remote http:// url.

Don't forget to add crossdomain.xml into your site, so you enable the cross-domain requests.